# Can Boost regex_replace executes in parallel?

Tags: c++, regex, multithreading, boost

I've tried to use boost thread and regex in my code, but confused by the behavior of `regex_replace`.

In the test class, I try to execute regex_replace `2000000` times, seperated by `THREAD_NUM` threads:

```
class ThreadClass {
public:
    ThreadClass() {
        _urlExp.assign(L"/*a regex expression here*/", wregex::icase);
    }
    void runThread() {
        for (int i=0; i<2000000/THREAD_NUM; i++) {
        wstring wtext(L"/*a long url here*/");
        regex_replace(wtext, _urlExp, L"[URL]");
    }
}
private:
    wregex _urlExp;
};
```

Afterwards, `main` calculates average time cost:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    ThreadClass tc1;
    //ThreadClass tc2;
    timeval tstart, tend;
    gettimeofday(&tstart, NULL);
    boost::thread thrd1(boost::bind(&ThreadClass::runThread, &tc1));
    //boost::thread thrd2(boost::bind(&ThreadClass::runThread, &tc2));
    thrd1.join();
    //thrd2.join();
    gettimeofday(&tend, NULL);
    double cost = tend.tv_sec - tstart.tv_sec + (tend.tv_usec - tstart.tv_usec) / 1000000; // calculate in second
    cout << cost << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As I comment, the code cost 28.58s when running with only one thread; however, if I uncomment the second thread, the code cost 36.28s.

When 2-thread are used, the CPU is in fact 200%. I understand that the 2-thread time should be >14.29s due to multithread cost, but how can it be >28.58s ?

Is regex_replace in fact not paralleled and threads are waiting each other? Or there is something wrong with my code or compiling?

uname -a:

```
Linux e100069200229.zmf 2.6.32-220.23.2.ali927.el5.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 28 14:57:06 CST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

16 cores CPU, boost 1.49.0, gcc 4.1.2, compile with `-O2`.

Comment: And, where is `THREAD_NUM` defined?

Comment: oh sry: `THREAD_NUM` is set to 1 when the second thread commented out, and 2 when uncommented.

Comment: I am writing this comment here, because my Answer doesn't solve the issue (due to it being issue in pasted code, well, except that `(tend.tv_usec - tstart.tv_usec) / 1000000` will always yield zero, since `tv_usec` is guaranteed to be less than 1000000, and there's integer division being performed here, change to 1000000.0 to perform floating point division), and I'll delete it.

Comment: However, I can't reproduce your problem. By changing your code, so that it would compile under Windows (mainly the elapsed time calculation code - used functions), and for it to be more re-runnable - so it would calculate benchmarks for multiple thread counts, and running for multiple times, with a single setting (thread count), and averaging results, to avoid random variances. The results are as follows: `Thread Count = 1; Time elapsed = 30.65s`, `Thread Count = 2; Time elapsed = 19.31s`, `Thread Count = 3; Time elapsed = 15.86s`, `Thread Count = 4; Time elapsed = 13.86s`.

Comment: Also, I needed to change the `boost::thread`, to the `std::thread`, since I don't have boost on my machine. Maybe there is an issue with `boost::thread`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thank you, the time listed is very reasonable. btw, which library did you use to replace `boost::regex`? c++11 is not allowed in our servers :(

Comment: Oh, derp, I didn't notice that regex_replace was from boost in your case. I  used the C++11 ones, that are in `std`.